# "Take something from someone" vs. "take something away from someone" in the sense of depriving someone of someting by force, authority or stealing

Tags: difference, phrasal-verbs

Could you tell me if there is any difference in meaning between *take something from someone* and *take something away from someone* in the sense of depriving someone of someting by force, authority or stealing? For example:

> My mom **took** my phome (**away**) **from** me. She won't give it back until my homework is done.
>
> Robbers tried to **take** my wallet (**away**) **from** me, but a police officer showed up and busted them.
>
> The government is out to **take** the freedoms of its people (**away**) **from** them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the context, but "took away" carries the idea of *removing* something from you with a degree of permanency, rather than just taking it out of your hands.

With your example of a phone, "she took it from me" could be used to mean she just held it in her hands for a moment to read something, and then gave it back to you. "She took it away from me" suggests it has been *confiscated*. If you wanted to remove any ambiguity you could say "My mom has *confiscated* my phone", although you do add that she did it until your homework was finished, so that clears it up in a similar way.

With your other example of things like human rights, it seems pretty obvious that "taking away" these is a permanent act.